# Calculating and changing the value in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I get JSON by api:

```
  public getJsonData(): Observable<any[]>{
    let uri = 'http://localhost:8000/api/product/';
    return this.http.get(uri)
          .map((response: Response) => {
              let items = response.json(); /* Here is where the table is filled with data. */
              return items;
      }).catch((error:any) => Observable.throw('Error retrieving the data.'));
  }
```

Data comes in the following form

```
[
    {
        "id": 46,
        "treaty_number": "rr2",
        "days_left_before_the_next_payment": null,
        "next_payment_date_1": "2017-10-01",
        "next_payment_date_2": "2017-11-21",
        "next_payment_date_3": "2017-12-29",
        "next_payment_date_4": null,
        "next_payment_date_5": null,
        etc
    }, etc
```

I need to calculate how many days remain until the next payment on the current date. And modify JSON by writing the value in days_left_before_the_next_payment. 
Pseudocode:

```
    if(Date.now < next_payment_1){
        days_left_before_the_next_payment = next_payment1 - Date.now
    } else if (Date.now < next_payment_2){
        days_left_before_the_next_payment = next_payment2 - Date.now
    } ..
```

And are there any modules to check it once a day? Like cron on the server. 

 Angular 4, TS v.2.4.1
Thanks.

Comment: you can use it inside of a `setInterval`

Comment: I assume this code is running on the client, correct?  if so, the client would need to be running the website for this code to execute, which seems very fragile.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @robbymurphy Yes, that's right, it works on the client. Data comes in JSON by API, then we work with it.

Comment: if that's really what you want to do, then @RahulSingh 's suggestion would work.

Comment: @robbymurphy I'm more interested in how to properly modify JSON in accordance with the date verification.

Comment: @Fill if response.json() is a string then you need to call JSON.parse(response.json()) to parse the string into an object.  Then you can manipulate it like any other javascript object.  You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/) to easily calculate the time difference.